# Only fetch email using google-signin

Tags: google-signin

I'm using the google sign-in example from https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/ (code pasted below for posterity).

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

By default this requests both 'email' and 'profile' scopes. This means when my users are asked to authorise my the login, it says `To continue, Google will share your name, email address, and profile picture with <app name>`. However, I only need their email address, and don't want to put them off wondering what I'm going to do with their profile picture etc.

I've tried asking only for email and also explicitly disabling basic profile info using the following code, but this doesn't change the message that the google sign-in page gives.

```
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="email">
<meta name="google-signin-fetch_basic_profile" content="false">
```

How can I request my users email address without google warning them that I'll have access to their profile info and picture too?

Comment: Once you have a user's email address, their public name and profile photo are accessible (e.g. when adding a contact in gmail or docs), so we wrote the legal disclosure on this sign in screen such that even if only the email address is directly shared, it's apparent to the user that their name and profile picture will also be available. So this is by design and unfortunately can't be changed...

Comment: Thanks very much @StevenSoneff that's the info I needed (because I can explain that to my users).