# Request only 'openid' scope from Google Sign-In for Websites

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-oauth

I'm integrating Google sign-in to my web app, but no matter what I specify, it always shows a warning in the login flow:

> To continue, Google will share your name, email address, and profile picture with [app name].

I don't need or want the name, email address, or profile picture of my users; I just need a token_id. I'm aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965244/only-fetch-email-using-google-signin) where the developer wants only the email address, and it is explained that the other details can be derived from the email address anyway, but in this case I don't want the email address either.

Following the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig) I've set:

```javascript
function login() {
  gapi.auth2.init({
    client_id: myClientIdHere,
    cookie_policy: 'none',
    fetch_basic_profile: false,    // <-- remove basic profile
    scope: 'openid',               // <-- request only openid
    ux_mode: 'redirect', // <-- using redirect to avoid popup blocker issues
    redirect_uri: myRedirectUriHere,
  }).then((GoogleAuth) => {
    GoogleAuth.signIn() // [etc]
  });
}

function init() {
  gapi.load('auth2', login);
}
```

Inspecting network requests shows that this is directing the user towards:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=[myRedirectUri]&response_type=permission%20id_token&scope=openid&openid.realm=&client_id=[myClientId]&ss_domain=[myDomain]&fetch_basic_profile=false&gsiwebsdk=2

Which looks correct. I've tried tweaking that URL and manually navigating to it and no matter what I change it always seems to show the warning.

In my Google API console project under Credentials -> OAuth consent screen -> Scopes for Google APIs, I can see that "email", "profile" and "openid" are all listed, and I can't find any option to remove them.

I don't know if it's actually sending me that information when a user signs in, but I'd like to remove the warning from the login screen.

How can I use Google sign-in **just** for sign-in? How do I prevent it giving me profile / email address information?

Comment: did u find a solution for this? I am also having the same requirement

Comment: @Kiran no, not with Google's sign in. Unless you're tied to Google you might want to consider looking at other OAuth providers.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an access token back from Google, you can call the userinfo endpoint and obtain user profile information using the openid scope, so even though you don't need the email and profile information, you can still obtain that information through the userinfo endpoint [1].

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtaininguserprofileinformation

Comment: Is it not possible to disable this functionality for my app? Since I only need a token_id, another option would be to block the creation of access tokens entirely for my app (an access token is required by that endpoint). I imagine there must be a way, because this is rather leaky for a large company like Google.

Comment: If you're referring to the ID token, it contains the email ID, name and profile picture information [1].

[1] https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#obtainuserinfo

Comment: I checked the ID tokens I'm receiving and they don't contain most of that information (I guess because I didn't ask for it). The token contains: `iss`, `sub`, `azp`, `aud`, `iat`, `exp` and `nonce`.