# how to fetch only email using google_sign_in

Tags: flutter, google-signin

I'm using flutter [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package in my app.
Even if I only use 'email' scope, it requests other user profile info (e.g., name or photo).
There's no button to remove other scopes in google OAuth consent screen.

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965244/only-fetch-email-using-google-signin), but I guess it's possible now:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2clientconfig

But I can't find how to set "fetch_basic_profile" config.

Is there anyway to fetch only email in google sign in?

[image]